# Can anyone suggest me to take xpath of these fields

Tags: python, xpath

```html
<div class="the_content">
   <p><strong>Niki Jones Agency, Inc</strong></p>
<p>Ms. Niki Jones</p>
<p>39 Front Street</p>
<p>Port Jervis</p>
<p>NY,&nbsp;12771</p>
<p>(845) 856-1266</p>
<p>njones@nikijones.com</p>
<p>www.Nikijones.com</p>
<p>20 Years in the PR &amp; Marketing business : Graphic design, Publications, Websites design&amp; Development, Digital Ads, Campaigns, Social Media, Direct Mail, Website security,ADA compliance 508</p>
<div class="apss-social-share apss-theme-1 clearfix">




<div class="the_content">
   <p><strong>JMB Electric Supply, LLC</strong></p>
<p>Joanne M. Barish</p>
<p>17 Belmont Street</p>
<p>White Plains, New York 10605</p>
<p>Tel:&nbsp;(914) 260-1895</p>
<p>Fax: 914-722-3277</p>
<p>Email:&nbsp;jmbelec@optionline.net</p>
<p>Website:&nbsp;http://jmbelec.net/</p>
<p>Description: Master distributor of Electronic and Magnetic Low Voltage Transformers &amp; Ballasts selling throughout the United States, as well as internationally.</p>
<div class="apss-social-share apss-theme-1 clearfix">
```

Comment: You're just a few clicks away. There is a direct way to do the same in modern browsers under the **Developer Tools**.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Use below xpath to get all div elements.

```
/div[@class='the_content']
```

Step 2: for each div elements,

For company name

```
/p/strong
```

For other p tags:

```
/p[2]
```

2 is the 2nd p tag. So, you can use 3,4,5...

Please see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp